# protect drupal 7 content with a password without creating accounts

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

Is there a module to password protect a drupal sites content but without creating accounts for the visitor. I just need to simplify the experience so the user just puts in a pre definded password and then the content shows.

I did look but couldn't find anything.

These is how I need this to work.

I (Admin) create a password (or multipul passwords) that I can give to friends/family/clients which they will enter when they visit my site to access protected content. Needs to be simple and these people don't need drupal accounts for my site.. they are just visitors but have extra access to content.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This thread might contain a solution to your problem: http://drupal.org/node/1126898
This module http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_password seems to come colsest to what you want.

Comment: Thanks... checking it out now.